# How verify if a member is admin?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a bot for supergroups.
How I can verify if member is admin?

my lib:org.telegram 4.2 https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

I tried with ChatMember, GetChatAdministrators and SendMessage methods but I have no idea how insert parameters because they don't ask them but they have only .get option (null respose). Only GetChatAdministrators permit a .set method for ChatID but it give error

```
GetChatAdministrators getadmin = new GetChatAdministrators().setChatId(ChatIDSupergroup);
            ArrayList<ChatMember> s = null;
            try {
                s = getadmin.deserializeResponse(null); //Unable to deserialize response
            } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
ChatMember member = new ChatMember(); //There are only get options
String status=member.getStatus(); //null
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem but I couldn't find an answer from anywhere. Then I tried myself and finally today I found the following solution:

```
public List<ChatMember> getChatAdministrators(Long chatId){
    List<ChatMember> chatAdministrators = Collections.emptyList();
    try {
        chatAdministrators = execute(new GetChatAdministrators(String.valueOf(chatId)));
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return chatAdministrators;
}
```

This method returns list of administrators of telegram groups, supergroups or channels.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function adminCheck( id, chat_id ) {
    var bAdminCheck = false;
    var name = "";
    var aChatMember = getChatAdministrators( chat_id );
    var contents = JSON.parse( aChatMember );
    var i = 0;
    while( !bAdminCheck && ( i < contents.result.length ) ) {
        if( id == contents.result[i].user.id ) {
            bAdminCheck = true;  
        }
        i++;
    }  
    return {
    AdminCheck: bAdminCheck,
    };
}
```

Available methods
source:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods

getChatAdministrators

Use this method to get a list of administrators in a chat. On success, returns an Array of ChatMember objects that contains information about all chat administrators except other bots. If the chat is a group or a supergroup and no administrators were appointed, only the creator will be returned.